# ErrorBoundary as an Exception handler for businessrules

Tags: razor, blazor, radzen

I'm on a search for handling business rule validation at a more global scale. Any BusinessRuleException thrown should result in a notification to the user. I thought of using the new ErrorBoundary component as a base for my own class but it is troublesome. The implementation below works but it refreshes the whole screen on each error which is not nice. Maybe my approach is not the best solution. Any input is appreciated. Here's my solution so far.

My own Boundary class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using MyProjects.Core.Exceptions;
using Radzen;

namespace MyProjects.Infrastructure
{
    public class MyProjectsBusinessRuleErrors : ErrorBoundary
    {
        [Inject]
        private NotificationService _notificationService { get; set; } = default!;

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
        }

        protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            if(exception is BusinessRuleException)
            {
                _notificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Error, exception.Message);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            return base.OnErrorAsync(exception);
        }

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            if (CurrentException is null || CurrentException is BusinessRuleException)
            {
                builder.AddContent(0, ChildContent);
            }
            else
            {
                base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using MyProjects.Infrastructure

<RadzenTooltip/>
<RadzenDialog/>
<RadzenNotification/>

<PageTitle>MyProjects</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            <MyProjectsBusinessRuleErrors @ref="errorBoundary">
                <ChildContent>
                    @Body
                </ChildContent>
                <ErrorContent>
                    An error has occured
                </ErrorContent>
            </MyProjectsBusinessRuleErrors>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

And code behind:

```
using MyProjects.Infrastructure;

namespace MyProjects.Shared
{
    public partial class MainLayout
    {
        MyProjectsBusinessRuleErrors? errorBoundary { get; set; }

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            errorBoundary?.Recover();

            base.OnParametersSet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - it seems your code is working, but you don't like it? Do you have a specific question rather than asking for vague comments?

Comment: The page refreshes/reloads on each error which is not nice.

Comment: The error boundary implementation looks a little overkill. Check out the implementation and source shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72989456/591285

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that one. Looks promising. I'll give that a try.

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for. This solution again forces a new page to open with a yellow bar on top with the exceptions. I just want to Notify the user a business rule was violated with a nice floating pop-up from Radzen.